# Android Volley POST JSONObject with int, string and jsonobjects

Tags: android, json, android-volley

whats up

I'm trying to post on my server JSONObject.

I've tried some codes which I found on stack:

```
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/order";
    try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/order";
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("waiterId", 1);
        jsonBody.put("tableNumber", 4);
        jsonBody.put("remark", "asd");
        jsonBody.put("products", new JSONObject());
        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm getting error:

> E/Volley: [275] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.0.2.2:8080/order
>   E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.ServerError

Or this:

```
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/order";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("waiterId", 1);
        jsonObject.put("tableNumber", 1);
        jsonObject.put("remark", "zamowienie");
        jsonObject.put("products", new JSONObject());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // As of f605da3 the following should work
            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
            if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                try {
                    String res = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                    // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e2) {
                    // returned data is not JSONObject?
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    Singleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

Error:

> E/Volley: [275] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.0.2.2:8080/order

In the second one I found tip to earse "Content-Type" but nothing changed.

Earlier I added objects using Postman, like this:

{ 
    "waiterId" : 3,
    "tableNumber" : 3,
    "remark" : "orderRemark",
    "products" : []
}

What is the problem? Maybe Im adding the "products" badly. How to add multiple 'products' or post json without 'products'?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I tried change JSONObject to jsonObject = new JSONObject("{ \"waiterId\" : 3, \"tableNumber\" : 3, \"remark\" : \"orderRemark\", \"products\" : [] }");. Now I dont have code 400 problem. It is just not posting new element. It dont show any error message :< (with both codes)

EDIT 2:
I've tried other method. It doesnt worked as well.

```
class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        Log.d("A","1");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("waiterId", 1);
            Log.d("A","2");
            jsonObject.put("tableNumber", 1);
            jsonObject.put("remark", "zamowienie");
            jsonObject.put("products", new JSONObject());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/order"); 
        URLConnection urlConn;
        DataOutputStream printout;
        DataInputStream input;
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput (true);
        urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
        urlConn.connect();

        printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream ());
        printout.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(),"UTF-8"));
        printout.flush ();
        printout.close ();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [simplified coding](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/) example, it works fine and easy

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.